# Is there a way to use Apple's OS X APIs through Java?

Tags: java, macos, swift

With Apple's recent announcement of its new XCTest UI testing APIs, I'm interested in seeing if I can integrate them in any way with an existing body of Java test code. To my understanding, this API, the Accessibility API, and others are only available to software written in Objective-C and Swift in XCode.

I don't mind taking the opportunity to learn Swift in order to interface with the UI testing API. Is there some reasonable way to create a Swift wrapper library for the API functionality I'm interested in so that I can integrate it with my Java-based software?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have not much fun with it, since a UI test framework integrates in more ways with the tested code than might be obvious.

There are several Java UI testing frameworks, probably integrating with your favorite IDE.

To choose the framework, you might consider

- the Java UI framework supported (Swing, AWT, Java FX, Android...)
- integration with your favorite API
- do you want open source or commercial support?

So don't look for Java UI testing frameworks in general but for your specific UI technology like Android or JavaFX.

Comment: I'm not trying to test my Java application. I'm trying to extend an existing Java test framework to support testing OS X apps. This requires integrating with OS X's Accessibility API in some way.